# python-pptx duplicate slide PPT will be damaged

Tags: python, python-pptx

I found that when using the method of duplicate slide, if there is a chart on the page, PPT will be damaged, so I used this method to copy a slide with a chart and modify the title of the chart on one page, and the title of the chart on the other page is also modified inexplicably

```
def duplicate_slide(pres,index):

    template = pres.slides[index]
    blank_slide_layout = pres.slide_layouts[index]
    copied_slide = pres.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

    for shp in template.shapes:
        el = shp.element
        newel = copy.deepcopy(el)
        copied_slide.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(newel, 'p:extLst')

    for _, value in six.iteritems(template.part.rels):
        # Make sure we don't copy a notesSlide relation as that won't exist
        if "notesSlide" not in value.reltype:
            copied_slide.part.rels.add_relationship(
                value.reltype, value._target, value.rId
            )

    return copied_slide
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, duplicating a slide is not a simple as just cloning the slide XML, which is what your `duplicate_slide()` method does. That works for some simple cases, but not for slides with charts.

In particular, a chart is a separate package-part ("file") within the PPTX package (zip archive). If you just copy the relationships from one slide to the other, like you do here, then you have two slides pointing to the same chart-part. This is why changing the chart title in one slide changes it in the other as well, because the same single chart is displayed on both slides.

In order to get the behavior you seem to be looking for, you would need to also duplicate the chart part and form a relationship from the new slide to that *new* chart part.

That's not a simple enough process for me to just provide here a few lines of code to do it, but hopefully this explains for you why you are seeing the behavior you are.

Comment: Thank you very much, scanny,Is there a mature way to copy a whole page of PPT？

Answer (score 0):

I managed to merge two PowerPoint files with the following code:

```
def move_slides(prs1, prs2):
    """Duplicate each slide in prs2 and "moves" it into prs1.
    Adds slides to the end of the presentation"""

    def _get_blank_slide_layout(pres):
        layout_items_count = [len(layout.placeholders) for layout in pres.slide_layouts]
        min_items = min(layout_items_count)
        blank_layout_id = layout_items_count.index(min_items)
        layout_0 = pres.slide_layouts[blank_layout_id]
        for shape in layout_0.shapes:
            sp = shape.element
            sp.getparent().remove(sp)
        return layout_0

    for slide in prs2.slides:
        sl = prs1.slides.add_slide(_get_blank_slide_layout(prs1))
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            newel = copy.deepcopy(shape.element)
            sl.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(newel, 'p:extLst')
        try:
            sl.shapes.title.text = slide.shapes.title.text
            sl.placeholders[0].text = slide.placeholders[0].text
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error \"{e}\", suppressing it...")
    return prs1
```

This function wants two `Presentation` objects and outputs a file which can be correctly opened with Microsoft Office PowerPoint with no errors